# magento filter order by product id and customer id

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

How can I get all magento orders ordered by a specific customer containing a specific product?
I tried the following:

```
        $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $customer_eamil = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerEmail();


        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $product->original_price = $product->getPrice();
        $productID = $product->getId();

        $fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-01-01')));
        $toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productID))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)
        ;
```

But all I get is an error in my magento error.log:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_id' in 'where clause''

I am using magent 1.9.2

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is pretty obvious... In your database there is no table with the column customer_id!

Comment: yeah I know. But how can I combine the two conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code to get desire result:

```
$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$customer_eamil = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerEmail();

$event = $observer->getEvent();
$product = $event->getProduct();
$product->original_price = $product->getPrice();
$productID = $product->getId();

$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-01-01')));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $productID));

$orders->getSelect()->join(array('sales_order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'main_table.order_id = sales_order.entity_id and customer_id=' . $customer_id, array('sales_order.entity_id'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orders->getData());
exit;
```

Please check data available using above filter in DB.

Comment: than you for your answer. It didn't worked.. I get an integrity constraint violation: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous'

Comment: Please remove created_at and try this once because above script working here.